# Difference between `const var_name` vs `const {var_name}` in JS

Tags: javascript, electron

Reference: http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/

```
const electron = require('electron');
const {app} = electron;
```

What is the difference between `const var_name` and `const {var_name}`?
When should I use `const var_name` or `const {var_name}`?

Comment: This is called _Destructuring assignment_ you can read more about it at MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following makes the variable "electron" reference what is returned from the require function:

```
const electron = require("electron")
```

The following is called a [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and makes the variable "app" reference whatever the property "app" of electron is referencing:

```
const {app} = electron;
```

It is the equivalent of writing:

```
const app = electron.app;
```